# Ecr passport for Indian student studying in US school

Tags: passports

My Son is a student of Grade 11 in US and will be joining Grade 12 coming Aug-18 . He holds a valid US F1 Visa , which is Valid till 2020. He joined this school in 2015 , and did his grade 9th (2016) , 10th   (2017) and 11th (2018) from there .

He holds an Indian Passport , and his passport is expiring In dec 2018 .He came to Delhi on in May-18 for his summer break .As per our understanding , his passport should have at least 6 months validity at the time of  travel. As he has to join back his school on 8th Aug-18 after his summer break , we have been advised by our travel agent to get his  passport renewed before his travel.

When we went to the passport office yesterday , the passport office were ready to renew his passport , but , as My has not cleared his class 10th exam in India , they are giving him the passport under ECR category - ECR means Emigration check required . Holders of ECR passports need a clearance called an Emigration Check from the Government of India's Protector of Emigrants when going to selected countries on a work visa. The Selected countries doesn’t include USA. Earlier he had a passport under ECNR Category .

My query to you is specific to a situation at the time of  Vishal’s Landing at the USA airport , and the query is do you foresee Vishal having  a problem with US immigration , if he travels back in Aug-18 with his renewed passport under ECR category ?

Comment: This should perhaps be migrated to [Expatriates.SE].

Answer (score 2):

The Emigration Check Required (ECR) category was created by the Indian Government to ensure that workers from India are not being tricked to work in exploitative conditions in certain countries. This list of countries includes: United Arab Emirates (UAE), The Kingdom of Saudi Arabia (KSA), Qatar, Oman, Kuwait, Bahrain, Malaysia, Libya, Jordan, Yemen, Sudan, Afghanistan, Indonesia, Syria, Lebanon, Thailand, Iraq. Having a ECR passport means that going to these countries on a work visa requires a special permit from the Office of the [Protector General of Emigrants](http://mea.gov.in/protector-general-emigrants.htm) of the Ministry of External Affairs.

As you can see, this is a requirement solely created to be use by Indian government bodies, and has no bearing on your son's studies in the United States. This is because of the following reasons:

- The United States cannot enforce an Indian government regulation.
- The United States is not on the list of ECR countries.
- Your son is not going to any of the 18 above mentioned countries to work, but only going to the United States to study.